# phpBB3 style - images don't show

Tags: image, forum, phpbb

I, I just installed 3.0.7 theme into my phpBB 3.0.8, and I can't see any theme images. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Themes in phpBB tend not to be the friendliest towards upgrades. Use firebug / some other code checker to just check the URLS to the images that aren't showing and check they're there...

It may also have something to do with the fact that many themes are based off the default PHPbb theme and require it (and its images to be there) - So check that out too... Prosilver I think its called.

Comment: Paths to images are right, but when I try to open the whole image, I get something like this:

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /subdom/forum/styles/Chronicles/imageset/site_logo.gif on this server."

Comment: Then you need to make sure that the images / folders have the right permissions... 644 should do the job. Then also make sure that the files have the right owner and group... This depends entirely on your server setup.